# am I using Dictionary wrong, it seems it too slow

Tags: c#

I've used VS profilier and noticed that ~40% of the time program spends in the lines below.
I'm using `title1` and `color1` because either Visual Studio or Resharper suggested to do so. Are there any perfomance issues in the code below?

```
Dictionary<Item, int> price_cache = new Dictionary<Item, int>();
....


string title1 = title;
string color1 = color;
if (price_cache.Keys.Any(item => item.Title == title && item.Color == color))
{
    price = price_cache[price_cache.Keys.First(item => item.Title == title11  && item.Color == color1)];
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to me Dictionary related issure, you don't just query a dictionary but also query the Keys collection. After this it's important to know how big is your dictionary and how often this code is executed, to give yuo some reasonable answer.

Comment: dictionary contains 200-1000 items. code executed 100-500 times per second

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your `Keys.Any` method iterates through all keys in your dictionary to find if there is a match. After that, you use the `First` method to do the same thing again.

Dictionary is suited for operations when you already have the key and want to get the value fast. In that case, it will calculate the **hash code** of your key (`Item`, in your case) and use it to "jump" to the bucket where your item is stored.

First, you need to make your custom comparer to let the `Dictionary` know how to compare items.

```
class TitleColorEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
     public bool Equals(Item a, Item b) 
     {
          // you might also check for nulls here
          return a.Title == b.Title && 
              a.Color == b.Color;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
     {
          // this should be as much unique as possible,
          // but not too complicated to calculate
          int hash = 17;
          hash = hash * 31 + obj.Title.GetHashCode();
          hash = hash * 31 + obj.Color.GetHashCode();
          return hash;
     }
}
```

Then, instantiate your dictionary using your custom comparer:

```
Dictionary<Item, int> price_cache = 
    new Dictionary<Item, int>(new TitleColorEqualityComparer());
```

From this point on, you can simply write:

```
Item some_item = GetSomeItem();
price_cache[some_item] = 5; // to quickly set or change a value
```

or, to search the dictionary:

```
Item item = GetSomeItem();
int price = 0;
if (price_cache.TryGetValue(item, out price))
{
    // we got the price
}
else
{
    // there is no such key in the dictionary
}
```

**[Edit]**

And to emphasize again: **never** iterate the `Keys` property to look for a key. If you do that, you don't need a `Dictionary` at all, you can simply use a list and get same (even slightly better performance).

Comment: thanks, because `Item` in my code implements equals and hashCode i think I don't need custom comparer?

Comment: @javapowered: yes, if it is implemented to compare the properties you need, you don't need a custom comparer. It could be useful, however, if you decided to have separate dictionaries, each organized by a different combination of properties. If your `Equals` implementation compares properties which are not compared in the custom comparer, but are irrelevant to your dictionary, then you should use the comparer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an IEqualityComparer as shown in the sample code on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx and make it calculate the hash code based on the title and color.

Answer (score 1):

As Jesus Ramos suggested (when he said use a different data structure), you could make the key a string that is a concatenation of the title and color, then concatenate the search string and look for that.  It should be faster.

So a key could look like `name1:FFFFFF` (the name, a colon, then the hex of the color), then you would just format the search string the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `price_cache.Keys.Any()` with `price_cache.Keys.SingleOrDefault()` and this way you can store the result in a variable, check for nullity and if not you already have the searched item instead of searching for it twice like you do here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fast access to your hashtable, you need to implement the GetHashCode and Equals functioning:

```
public class Item 
{
.....
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.color.GetHashCode() + this.title.GetHashCode())/2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        var item = o as Item;
        return (item != null) && (item.color == color) &&  (item.title== title) ;
    }
```

Access you dictionary like:

```
Item item = ...// create sample item
int price = 0;

price_cache.ContainsKey(item);
price_cache[item];
price_cache.TryGetValue(item, out price);
```

Comment: equals and hashcode implemented for `Item` in my code, probably i should try creating `Item` object and "jumping to bascet" as Groo suggested

Comment: hm the problem is that Item contains one other field, say "storage". and to get price "Title" and "Color" should match, but "Storage" can be any.

Comment: Create a cache dictionary like: Dictionary<CacheItem, List<Item>> where the CacheItem is based on the color and titel, then search the list for the correct item.

Comment: @peer: that's a bit of an overkill (first to wrap each `Item` in a `CacheItem`, then to do an additional search of a list or items). That's what custom comparers are for.